# Xamarin.Forms iOS UIKit.UIImage Error

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, uikit, xamarin.forms

I've been working with making a mobile app using Xamarin.Forms. I have everything working on android, but when I try to launch on iOS I get the error:

```
System.Exception: Could not initialize an instance of the type 'UIKit.UIImage': the native 'initWithContentsOfFile:' method returned nil.
>It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.
....
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Edit:
Here is the code it gives me the error on, but I have the feeling something else is causing it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace CloudClubv1._2_.iOS
{
    public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
            // you can specify it here.
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you're loading/assigning the image.

Comment: Any unhandled exception is going to bubble up to Main - but that is obviously not the source of the error.  I would assume it is being caused by some Image element that is corrupt or missing on iOS, but works on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the error was being caused by trying to give an icon to a tabbed view. This works fine on android, but apparently on ios it isn't supported, so to fix the error I just had to comment out the line where the an icon for the tabbed view was set.

Comment: Im currently having this issue. but how did you manage to set an image to the iOS version then?

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember exactly, but I think our short term solution was just taking out the icons for the time being, or making it android specific for the moment. That can buy you time so you can ask the question on xamarin's official forums - they should be able to answer that question there.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - but mine occurred after moving all my images into an `Images/` folder within `Resources/` instead of the images being directly in `Resources/`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure on IOS project, set Resources/image properties to BundledResources. In my project they were set to AndroidResources, when I corrected to BundledResources my start working fine.